# Perl Filter using cmd and piped arguments

Tags: regex, perl, stdin, argv

I am writing a Perl script (filter.pl) that filters data presented on STDIN, changing all occurrences of one string to another and outputting all input lines, changed and unchanged to STDOUT. My usage is as follows:

```
USAGE: ./filter.pl 'FROMSTRING' 'TOSTRING'
```

For example, here is how I run my script:

```
echo "this is a test" | filter.pl 'a' '@'
#output: "this is @ test"
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Verify two cmd arguments are present.     
if ($#ARGV !=2)
    {
    print "Usage: ./filter.pl FROMSTRING TOSTRING";
    exit(1);
    }

#read from STDIN, replace FROMSTRING with TOSTRING, then print output
while (<>)
    {
    s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/gi;
    print $_;
    exit(0);
    }
```

Basically this script uses "(STDIN)" to read each line of input, Uses $_ to access each line read, uses "s/// to change all occurrences of FROMSTRING to TOSTRING on each line, and prints them out.

When I run this from the command line I get an error: command not found. I suspect this is because I don't know the difference between piped-in and invocation arguments in Perl? Also wondering if I am on the right track with this.

thanks.

Comment: #1 How do you invoke the script? Probably the error is not related to the Perl code.

#2 Most likely you do not want to terminate the program after the first line processed. So remove the `exit(0);`.

Comment: Is `filter.pl` executable and in your `PATH`? (Also, move the `exit(0);` outside and after your while loop.)

Comment: Oh I didn't realize my exit(0) was inside my while statement. Moved it out and now it works fine. THANKS!!!

Comment: Also: `$#ary` is the index of the last element in `@ary`.  So your condition on `$#ARGV` demands that the last element of `@ARGV` has index 2 so that `@ARGV` has indices `0, 1, 2`; _three_ elements. What you want is `@ARGV != 2`.

Comment: "Command not found" is probably from not making `filter.pl` executable.

Answer (score 2):

`<>` is shorthand for `<ARGV>`, where `ARGV` is the special filehandle that can either refer to standard input, or to an input stream of all files names in `@ARGV`.

Since your script makes use of `@ARGV` for purposes other than specifying input files, you can't use `ARGV` to read from standard input. You should use `<STDIN>` explicitly to read from standard input instead of `<>`.

```
while (<STDIN>)
{
    s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/gi;
    print $_;
    exit(0);       # <---- this probably belongs outside the loop
}
```

Comment: A better solution would be shift off the first two elements of `@ARGV`: `die("Usage: ...\n") if @ARGV < 2; my ($pat, $repl) = splice(@ARGV, 0, 2); while (<>) { ...; s/$pat/$repl/gi; ... }`